# Change Feed Consistency Level

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Assuming we do not have strong consistency set, when using azure functions change feed are we guaranteed to get the latest document when querying against the same partition? Also, are all queries issues from within the change feed guaranteed the latest records since the change feed runs on the write region?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can read changefeed from any read region. Check the pull request https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/pull/508. This code will be part of function soon. But using Change feed processor library you can do it today.

If you are reading it from write region then you are getting the current document. However, if you are reading it from any other read region then it will be dependent upon your consistency.

Comment: so is it correct to say then when dealing with a non geo replicated account you are essentially using strong consistency?