# How do conflicts affect the Azure Cosmos DB Change Feed in multi-master replication scenarios?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does the change feed only publish changes that have been fully replicated, or is it possible to see a document version that will ultimately be the victim of a conflict resolution?

Similar questions I've found that don't quite address this:

- [How does CosmosDB change feed behave in the presence of multi-master replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797774/how-does-cosmosdb-change-feed-behave-in-the-presence-of-multi-master-replication)
- [Azure cosmosdb changefeed for document collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580277/azure-cosmosdb-changefeed-for-document-collection)
- [Change Feed Consistency Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708952/change-feed-consistency-level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, change feed only exposes committed changes, tentative changes are not exposed. If a change is done in a satellite (secondary) region, and change feed reads from satellite, the change will get into the feed only after it’s merged in the hub (primary region) and sent back to the satellite. Thus no multiple versions of the same change.

Comment: I note you said "currently" - this is the most desirable behaviour in my view; the converse would doubtless add significant complexity to applications dependent on the change feed and needing robust observability. Thanks for the info.

Comment: We have no plans to change this so you can disregard "currently" thx